# Is there a reason a newer kernel would cause a wifi adapter to be much slower than with an older kernel?

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel

A kernel update from 4.4.0.31 to >4.4.0.64 seems to have caused my wifi connection to go from 25Mbps to <3-8Mbps. If I boot using the older kernel, -.31, I get normal speeds back. Is this something affecting anyone else? I don't really know how to investigate this.

Here is a bunch of information on my wireless info:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 24 Feb 2017 16:17 CST -0600

Booted last: 24 Feb 2017 00:00 CST -0600

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-64-generic #85-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 20 11:50:30 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5410]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 04f3:21d0 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0c45:64cb Microdia 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0483:91d1 STMicroelectronics Sensor Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

iwlmvm                311296  0
mac80211              737280  1 iwlmvm
dell_wmi               16384  0
snd_soc_rt5640        114688  0
snd_soc_rl6231         16384  1 snd_soc_rt5640
iwlwifi               200704  1 iwlmvm
snd_soc_core          212992  2 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_ssm4567
cfg80211              565248  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
snd_pcm               106496  7 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core
sparse_keymap          16384  2 dell_wmi,intel_vbtn
wmi                    20480  2 dell_led,dell_wmi
video                  40960  2 i915,dell_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

wlp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.3  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::b211:6513:5a1d:4151/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3850 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2298 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4384052 (4.3 MB)  TX bytes:1432444 (1.4 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"DFNET2"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: ############   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=59/70  Signal level=-51 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:64   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp1s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp1s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      2790     1  0 16:15 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp1s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Wireless 7265 (Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         iwlwifi
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.4.0-64-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               16.242414.0
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/net/wlp1s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp1s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     ###### 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       048840aa-52c9-4436-ad28-e11fda56893c
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     54 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   048840aa-52c9-4436-ad28-e11fda56893c | DFNET2 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.3/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1488060943
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.1.3
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::b211:6513:5a1d:4151/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

SSID                  BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  * 
--                    <MAC '--' [AN1]>  Infra  153   5765 MHz  54 Mbit/s  85      ▂▄▆█  WPA2       no        
DFNET2                <MAC 'DFNET2' [AN2]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  75      ▂▄▆_  WPA2       yes     * 
ATT2R7K7a2            <MAC 'ATT2R7K7a2' [AN3]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  37      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
--                    <MAC '--' [AN4]>  Infra  40    5200 MHz  0 Mbit/s   37      ▂▄__  WEP        no        
NETGEAR79             <MAC 'NETGEAR79' [AN5]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  34      ▂▄__  WPA2       no        
MyCharterWiFia4-2G    <MAC 'MyCharterWiFia4-2G' [AN6]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  34      ▂▄__  WPA2       no        
--                    <MAC '--' [AN7]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  32      ▂▄__  WEP        no        
--                    <MAC '--' [AN8]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  30      ▂___  WPA2       no        
--                    <MAC '--' [AN9]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  22      ▂___  WPA2       no        
Flowers               <MAC 'Flowers' [AN10]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  19      ▂___  WPA2       no        
Flowers               <MAC 'Flowers' [AN11]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  15      ▂___  WPA2       no        
--                    <MAC '--' [AN12]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  14      ▂___  WEP        no        
GETCHO OWN DAMN WIFI  <MAC 'GETCHO OWN DAMN WIFI' [AN13]>  Infra  7     2442 MHz  54 Mbit/s  14      ▂___  WPA2       no        
The Vue Lofts WiFi    <MAC 'The Vue Lofts WiFi' [AN14]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  9       ▂___  --         no        

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/DFNET2 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=DFNET2 1 | type=wifi | permissions=user:def:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF1]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=DFNET2
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/DFNET2]] (600 root)
[connection] id=DFNET2 | type=wifi | permissions=user:ubuntu:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF1]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=DFNET2
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/Chicago (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

wlp1s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp1s0    Interface doesn't support scanning : Device or resource busy

##### module infos ######################

[iwlmvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-64-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     60ED6558F1225672289299A
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-64-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool)
parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)
parm:           tfd_q_hang_detect:TFD queues hang detection (default: true (bool)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-64-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     59E6C095E163EDB3ECF327B
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-64-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-64-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-13.ucode
srcversion:     4116E844336D79483D28F6F
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-64-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-64-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     A7DC879B6551813C20004F1
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-64-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlmvm]
init_dbg: N
power_scheme: 2
tfd_q_hang_detect: Y

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
d0i3_disable: Y
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
lar_disable: N
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: Y

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   11.004694] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode failed with error -2
[   11.004710] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode failed with error -2
[   11.004718] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode failed with error -2
[   11.427883] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   12.123454] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[   12.123790] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 2 times)
[   12.606159] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   12.840888] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
[   32.715784] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
[   32.716147] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 4 times)
[   32.813403] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[   41.566470] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'DFNET2' [AN2]>
[   41.572197] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'DFNET2' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[   41.574144] wlp1s0: authenticated
[   41.576690] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'DFNET2' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[   41.579891] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'DFNET2' [AN2]> (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=2)
[   41.582121] wlp1s0: associated
[   41.582166] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Maybe the driver was changed by the update... I don't know much about drivers either...

Comment: Hi Donald, *don't worry* the community will help you as fast as possibile.
You should add more information to your question if you want a good and fast answer: are you using a laptop? what is your network adapter? did you use a proprietary (non-free) driver? :-)

Comment: Unless there's an even more vital reason to use that 4.4.0.61 kernel, why not keep using the slightly older one that works? Later when there's an even newer kernel you can give it a try & see if the wifi is normal with it.

Comment: @LorenzoAncora there is a proprietary Intel driver for something, but the connection is this same using that driver or not.

Comment: @Xen2050 That's been my approach so far, just wanted to see if there's something that needs to be fixed or other people having the same problem... There's already been one new kernel (-.66) that still seems to cause the same issue...

Comment: Waiting for kernel fixes is never fun. Maybe a web search for your specific wifi adapter and "slow" may find something

Comment: There was a kernel that got pulled because it had **glitches** but I can't remember which one it was. Try -65 or -66 whichever the newest one is. I'm on my phone so can't check.